# Weird permissions problem with TeX Live 2013, Ubuntu 13.04, LuaTeX and problem fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive, ubuntu

**Update at bottom**

I recently installed vanilla TeX Live 2013 on my Ubuntu 13.04 system. Most everything works. It's just when I run into certain problematic fonts using LuaLaTeX that things go awry.

Take the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garmond Premier Pro}
Regular\\
\textit{Italics}\\
\textbf{Bold}}\\
\textit{\textbf{Bold Italics}}\\
\end{document}
```

If compiled with LuaTeX on my system, Garamond Med. Italic is used for italics (instead of the regular italic,) and Semi Bold Italic is used for bold italics (instead of the proper Bold Italic Font). Bold is done correctly.

I should be able to fix this by changing the `\setmainfont` command thusly:

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont=GaramondPremrPro-It.otf]{Garamond Premier Pro}
```

But this causes LuaLaTeX to barf:

```
luaotfload | db : reload initiated; reason: “unresolved font name: ‘garamond
premrproitotf’”
! LuaTeX error .../texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-lib    dir.lua:81: s
tack overflow.
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
l.13 {Garamond Premier Pro}
```

and it won't compile.  So here's where things get weird.  If I compile it as root it still pauses in the same place but soldiers on through and compiles correctly.  OK, that's not so weird, maybe, but here's the really weird part.  I created a new user on my system who is also able to compile that same code with the same pause.  In other words, it's only me, my main user, who cannot compile the code properly.

More weirdness. I have a couple of other fonts that cause problems. Some of them I could get around by copying the files from `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names` into `~/.texlive/2013/...` and the document would compile fine.

I haven't been able to figure out exactly under what circumstance the latter solution works and does not work but at least for Garamond Premier Pro it does not work.

I put "permissions" in the title because it feels like a permissions problem but the behavior is inconsistent so I'm not sure.  I could try re-installing but I'm not really sure what I did wrong the first time that lead to this issue.

Side note, I can specify *all* the font paths in `\setmainfont`, like {GaramondPremrPro.itf} and it works but then it won't use the different optical sizes. It's just combining the specific paths with `{Garamond Premier Pro}`that causes a problem.

**Update** Thanks to phg I'm now using the postscript names which helps in that at least my main user account is now able to process any font using LuaLaTeX. However, the main problem still persists, if there is a problematic font then my main account stops compiling with an error. If I compile the code as root or any other user then it will compile. At that point when I copy the files from `.../luatex-cache/generic/names/` to my home account then I too can compile the document successfully. Before I started using the postscript names some fonts would not compile at all even when I did this workaround.

So at least now it's not quite so critical but still annoying and puzzling.

Comment: That’s an issue with the font names and style synonyms. *medium* (which used to be treated as a synonym for *regular*) is now treated like bold. The font matching algorithm will terminate as soon as it finds a font whose style is one of the synonyms. Which one that is depends on the order in which files are processed and -- with the git version -- on whether it is located in the texmf or a system font. I’m pondering stategies to prioritize some of the synonyms but it’s a medium term goal. In the meantime, you can use the postscript names to assign fonts: ``ItalicFont=Garamond Premr Pro It,Bold

Comment: Wow. You cannot imagine my relief.  I've been battling this for two days straight and I really didn't want to have to reinstall and have it all not work again. So yeah, using the postscript names does the trick all the way around. And such a simple change. Thanks to you, Garamond Premier Pro is working to its full glory in my document. Thanks again!

Comment: You can try [this branch](https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload/tree/font-matching). It will prefer exact style matches (*bold*) over matches from synonyms (*medium*) and could fix your problem. In contrast to postscript names it should support design sizes.

Comment: @phg I installed this version but it didn't make any difference with the Garamond Premier Pro version I have. In any case, as you can see with my update to my original post, I'm still having basically the same issue though it's less critical.

Comment: The bad permissions may be caused by old cache or configuration files in your home directory that interfere with the new install. How did you get TL, using ``tlmgr`` or from your distro’s packages? Check whether there is a ``~/.texlive2013`` or ``~/.texmf`` directory and remove it, then try again.

Comment: @phg I had TL before from Ubuntu. I purged it then installed TL with tlmgr. I have several times deleted `~/.texlive2013 (I never had a ~/.texmf file to begin with) but to no avail. And again, it's only on certain typefaces that this happens.

Comment: @phg Do your comments here make an answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that does not seem to be generally reproducible.